# What could influence the visibility of my app on the store?

Tags: android, google-play

I've recently updated gradle to 3.4.0 and when uploading the build to the store I received a warning message letting me know that users will not be able to see the new build.

The only difference between the old apk and the new one is that the new one only has these native platforms 
`Native platforms`
`arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, x86, x86_64`

while the old one also has the `mips` abi.

I went to the store after a couple of hours after uploading he build and I can't see the new build.

Any ideas ?! Why does that influence the apk from being able to be seen from the store, if they're deprecated... ?!

Or could the problem come from another place?

**EDIT**

Could the problem arise from this instead by any chance?

```
// Butterknife requires Java 8.
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Here's my entire app level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.29.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {

    lintOptions { checkReleaseBuilds false }

    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    signingConfigs {
        releaseSign {
            storeFile file("$rootProject.projectDir/keystore_release.jks")
            storePassword 'xxxxx'
            keyAlias 'xxxx'
            keyPassword 'xxxx'
        }
    }

    // Butterknife requires Java 8.
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx.driver"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 27
        versionName "1.0.27"

        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

        multiDexEnabled true

        splits {
            abi {
                reset()
                include "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi-v8a", "x86_64", "mips", "mips64"
                universalApk true
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseSign
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        beta {
            applicationId "com.xxxx.driver.beta"

            dimension "default"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Driver Beta"
            resValue "string", "privacy_policy_url", "https://www.xxxxxx"

            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '"https://xxxxxxx"'
            buildConfigField "Boolean", "IS_BETA", "true"
            buildConfigField "String", "TENANT", '"xxxxx"'

        }
        production {
            applicationId "com.xxxxx.driver"

            dimension "default"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Driver"
            resValue "string", "privacy_policy_url", "https://www.xxxxx"

            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '"https://xxxxx"'
            buildConfigField "Boolean", "IS_BETA", "false"
            buildConfigField "String", "TENANT", '"xxxx"'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    }
}

configurations.all {
//    resolutionStrategy {
//        eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
//            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support' && details.requested.name != 'multidex') {
//                details.useVersion "28.0.0"
//            }
//        }
//    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha05'

    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'

    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    def work_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version"
// Optional - RxJava2 support
    implementation "androidx.work:work-rxjava2:$work_version"

    def futures_version = "1.0.0-beta01"
    implementation "androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:$futures_version"

    implementation 'com.github.delight-im:Android-AdvancedWebView:v3.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And my top level build.gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: If the new one got rid of mips, that would make it invisible to mips users.  The good news is that like 5 models of phones ever, and they weren't popular ones, and they're all like 8 years old now.  So I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Then ... what could it be ?! Could the target java 1.8 thing be an issue? I can't downgrade butterfly to a lower version, before it required java 1.8 as other conflicts come up and it won't build... I'm really, really stuck.

Comment: No, the 1.8 thing won't be a problem.  The mips thing would cause that banner but wouldn't cause an actual issue, it could be that for some reason your app is just slow to update right now (it takes a few hours sometimes).  I'd also double check that you didn't deploy  to a beta channel or do a percentage based rollout

Comment: The update was made 2 days ago, and another one yesterday, so time is not a factor, or it shouldn't be, we're not on the AppleStore. hehe. I DID upload to a beta chanel but the same app I have on the Production channel, and neither are visible. The odd thing is that I created a secondary application (new package name) on the store and the very first build uploaded is visible! New ones are not. I have no idea ... I sent a message to the support team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out myself. The solution was that, their system is buggy. There is nothing wrong with my app. I sent them an email and they answered after a week+. After that, everything is working fine. A number of days after posting this question, a colleague also had this issue with another app, so if you do happen to come across this issue send them an email and ask.